# MapKit: annotation don't display until zoom the map in iPhone

Tags: sqlite, core-data, annotations, mapkit

I expect once clicking the toolbar button like "Mapa", annotations will show in the visible map region. Data are fetched from CoreData (Sqlite). Everything works fine in iPhone Simulator, but when I test the app on my iPhone just some pins are displayed after clicking the button on toolbar and I need to zoom in and out several times to obtain all the pins.

the first image (http://www.aerodromoschile.com/IMG_0982.PNG) shows the screen before zoom it several times and the second (http://www.aerodromoschile.com/IMG_0981.PNG) is what I want to get from the begining

could you help me? here is the code

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "AerodromoAppDelegate.h"
#import "Aerodromo.h"
#import "DetalleViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@implementation mapViewController {
NSArray *locations;
}

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize mapView;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [(AerodromoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication      sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  self.managedObjectContext);
}

dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

NSLog(@"Main Thread Code"); 

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aerodromo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *foundObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (foundObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error)");
    return;
}

if (locations != nil) {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:locations];
}

locations = foundObjects;

self.title = @"Mapa Online";

UIBarButtonItem *showuser = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showUser:)];

UIBarButtonItem *boton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Boton" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(boton2:)];

NSArray *botones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:showuser, boton, nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = botones;


mapView.delegate = self;

// Creamos una coordenada inicial.
CLLocationCoordinate2D initialLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
initialLocation.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
initialLocation.longitude= self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;


// Esto situará el centro del mapa    
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(initialLocation, 50000, 50000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

 NSLog(@"antotaciones = %d", locations.count);

[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

 self.mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;

    NSLog(@"fin Thread Code");

}); // termino del queqe

//[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
//[self updateLocations];

}


- (void)showUser:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Boton1");
MKCoordinateRegion region =   MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 50000, 50000);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:NO];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

}


- (void)boton2:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"boton 2");
}


#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id   <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Aerodromo class]]) {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Aerodromo";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //annotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aero3.png"];
        //annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLocationDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView;
    button.tag = [locations indexOfObject:(Aerodromo *)annotation];

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
}


- (void)showLocationDetails:(UIButton *)button
{

NSLog(@"se apreto el boton");
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditLocation" sender:button];
}

@end
```

**EDITED CODE**

this is the las code that I'm using, I sill have the same problem....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [(AerodromoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  self.managedObjectContext);
}

UIBarButtonItem *showuser = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showUser:)];
UIBarButtonItem *boton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Boton" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(boton2:)];
NSArray *botones = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:showuser, boton, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = botones;

self.title = @"Mapa Online";
mapView.delegate = self;

// Creamos una coordenada inicial.
CLLocationCoordinate2D initialLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
//region.center = //self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
initialLocation.latitude = -33.40;//self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
initialLocation.longitude= -70.54;//self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;


// Esto situará el centro del mapa
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(initialLocation, 50000, 50000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
self.mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //Anything that is not part of the UI

    NSLog(@"ASync Thread Code");

    NSMutableArray *tempLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aerodromo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *foundObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (foundObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error)");
        return;
    }

    MKPointAnnotation *location; //If you're not using MKPointAnnotation: replace it
    for (location in foundObjects) {
        [tempLocations addObject:location];
    }
    locations = tempLocations.copy;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Update the UI
        NSLog(@"Getting back to the UI");

        NSLog(@"antotaciones = %d, %@", locations.count, locations);

        if (locations != nil) {
            [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
            [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        }

    });
});

NSLog(@"fin Thread Code");

}
```

Thanks for your help wkberg, when I used NSLog(@"antotaciones = %d, %@", locations.count, locations); to know what happen  with the data I realized that after the 7th row the NSFetchRequest does not load the data

here is the console:

```
2013-07-16 12:10:18.007 Aerodromo[13922:1207] ASync Thread Code
2013-07-16 12:10:18.045 Aerodromo[13922:907] Getting back to the UI
2013-07-16 12:10:18.090 Aerodromo[13922:907] antotaciones = 351, (
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0040> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0ad580 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p1> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 45;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Arica \";\n    Desig = SCAR;\n    Elev = \"123 -166\";\n    FrecTerr = IFR;\n    FrecTorre = 1;\n    Fuel = JP1;\n    Fuel2 = \"AVGAS 100/130\";\n    IdAd = 1;\n    IndexRegion = 1;\n    Larg1 = 2170;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 18;\n    LatM = 20;\n    LatS = 55;\n    Latitud = \"-18.349\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 70;\n    LonM = 20;\n    LonS = 19;\n    Longitud = \"-70.339\";\n    Nombre = Chacalluta;\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"02-20\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 15;\n    Superficie = \"Hormig\\U00f3n\";\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(58) 211116\";\n    TieneMetar = 1;\n    Uso = \"P\\U00daBLICO\";\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21d8e110 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21d8e460 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0470> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f098d30 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p2> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 23;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Arica \";\n    Desig = SCAE;\n    Elev = 328;\n    FrecTerr = 0;\n    FrecTorre = 0;\n    Fuel = \"No Tiene\";\n    Fuel2 = \"\";\n    IdAd = 2;\n    IndexRegion = 1;\n    Larg1 = 800;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 18;\n    LatM = 30;\n    LatS = 36;\n    Latitud = \"-18.51\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 70;\n    LonM = 17;\n    LonS = 21;\n    Longitud = \"-70.289\";\n    Nombre = \"El Buitre\";\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"09-27\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 15;\n    Superficie = Asfalto;\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(58) 201500 Anexo 31216\";\n    TieneMetar = 0;\n    Uso = MILITAR;\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e711e0 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e715e0 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0870> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a09c0 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p3> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 45;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Iquique \";\n    Desig = SCDA;\n    Elev = \"97-157\";\n    FrecTerr = \"VFR - IFR\";\n    FrecTorre = 1;\n    Fuel = JP1;\n    Fuel2 = \"AVGAS 100/130\";\n    IdAd = 3;\n    IndexRegion = 2;\n    Larg1 = 3350;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 20;\n    LatM = 32;\n    LatS = 07;\n    Latitud = \"-20.535\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 70;\n    LonM = 10;\n    LonS = 53;\n    Longitud = \"-70.181\";\n    Nombre = \"Diego Aracena\";\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"19-01\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 1;\n    Superficie = \"Hormig\\U00f3n\";\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(57)461200\";\n    TieneMetar = 1;\n    Uso = \"P\\U00daBLICO\";\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e71d00 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e71e70 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0670> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a09a0 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p4> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 20;\n    Ancho2 = 20;\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Pica \";\n    Desig = SCKP;\n    Elev = 12468;\n    FrecTerr = 0;\n    FrecTorre = 0;\n    Fuel = \"No Tiene\";\n    Fuel2 = \"\";\n    IdAd = 4;\n    IndexRegion = 2;\n    Larg1 = 3200;\n    Larg2 = 1034;\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 20;\n    LatM = 44;\n    LatS = 08;\n    Latitud = \"-20.736\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 68;\n    LonM = 41;\n    LonS = 42;\n    Longitud = \"-68.69499999999999\";\n    Nombre = Coposa;\n    NumeroPistas = 2;\n    Pista1 = \"17-35\";\n    Pista2 = \"10-28\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 1;\n    Superficie = Asfalto;\n    Superficie2 = Tierra;\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(57)417777\";\n    TieneMetar = 0;\n    Uso = PRIVADO;\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e72b80 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e72f70 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0a50> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0907c0 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p5> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 30;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Pozo Almonte\";\n    Desig = SCNV;\n    Elev = 3172;\n    FrecTerr = 0;\n    FrecTorre = 0;\n    Fuel = \"No Tiene\";\n    Fuel2 = \"\";\n    IdAd = 5;\n    IndexRegion = 2;\n    Larg1 = 1077;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 20;\n    LatM = 44;\n    LatS = \"05,4\";\n    Latitud = \"-20.735\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 69;\n    LonM = 37;\n    LonS = \"32,6\";\n    Longitud = \"-69.626\";\n    Nombre = \"Nueva Victoria\";\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"09-27\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 1;\n    Superficie = Vichufita;\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(57) 413620\";\n    TieneMetar = 0;\n    Uso = PRIVADO;\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e739e0 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e73800 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b0c20> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0920e0 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p6> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 18;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Antofagasta \";\n    Desig = SCGU;\n    Elev = 3347;\n    FrecTerr = 0;\n    FrecTorre = 0;\n    Fuel = \"No Tiene\";\n    Fuel2 = \"\";\n    IdAd = 6;\n    IndexRegion = 3;\n    Larg1 = 1200;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 24;\n    LatM = 8;\n    LatS = 11;\n    Latitud = \"-24.136\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 69;\n    LonM = 49;\n    LonS = 43;\n    Longitud = \"-69.82899999999999\";\n    Nombre = \"Aguas Blancas\";\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"13-31\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 2;\n    Superficie = Tierra;\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(2) 2063737\";\n    TieneMetar = 0;\n    Uso = PRIVADO;\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e744d0 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e74920 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b1020> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a1970 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p7> ; data: {\n    Ancho1 = 50;\n    Ancho2 = \"\";\n    Ancho3 = \"\";\n    Ciudad = \"Antofagasta \";\n    Desig = SCFA;\n    Elev = \"352- 455\";\n    FrecTerr = \"VFR - IFR\";\n    FrecTorre = 1;\n    Fuel = JP1;\n    Fuel2 = \"AVGAS 100/130\";\n    IdAd = 7;\n    IndexRegion = 3;\n    Larg1 = 2599;\n    Larg2 = \"\";\n    Larg3 = \"\";\n    LatG = 23;\n    LatM = 26;\n    LatS = 40;\n    Latitud = \"-23.444\";\n    Limitaciones = \"\";\n    Limitaciones2 = \"\";\n    Limitaciones3 = \"\";\n    LonG = 70;\n    LonM = 26;\n    LonS = 42;\n    Longitud = \"-70.44499999999999\";\n    Nombre = \"Cerro Moreno\";\n    NumeroPistas = 1;\n    Pista1 = \"01-19\";\n    Pista2 = \"\";\n    Pista3 = \"\";\n    RegionOrd = 2;\n    Superficie = Asfalto;\n    Superficie2 = \"\";\n    Superficie3 = \"\";\n    Telefono = \"(55) 269077\";\n    TieneMetar = 1;\n    Uso = \"P\\U00daBLICO\";\n    frec = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e75370 'frec'>\";\n    pdf = \"<relationship fault: 0x21e75190 'pdf'>\";\n})",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b1770> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a41c0 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p8> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b1f00> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0ad660 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p9> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b11e0> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f071c50 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p10> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b1b50> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a4930 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p11> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Aerodromo: 0x1f0b13c0> (entity: Aerodromo; id: 0x1f0a3190 <x-coredata://DEC0D4FE-F4A8-4739-9974-076071695E99/Aerodromo/p12> ; data: <fault>)",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatching the addAnnotations async. Annotations are part of the UI and should be on the main-thread. The reason they're not added until you zoom the map is because of your `regionWillChangeAnimated` code. By the time you zoom the async dispatch is finished on the iPhone, but it isn't at the moment when you're adding the annotations in `viewDidLoad`.

To solve your problem with the GCD:

In your `viewDidLoad` do something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
//Do UI stuff here:
//the mapView setup
//Region set
//and any other UI like: UILabels, UIbuttons etc.

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

//So now we start the async part:

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
 //Anything that is not part of the UI
 //Get your data for the annotations

 //And now get back to the main_queue sync:

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        locations = foundObjects; //As in your code
        //Update the UI
        NSLog(@"Getting back to the UI");

        if (locations != nil) {
         [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations]; //mapView.annotations to remove all...
         [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        }

    });
});
NSLog(@"End of viewDidLoad");
}
```

## From comments:

If still not all the annotations show up. Check if you're not calling `[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];` before your `locations` array is finished.
This could be done by `regionWillChangeAnimated` when adjusting the map to the users locations with your: `setRegion:region`.

## NSFetch Problem:

Ok as I'm less familiar with NSFetchRequest, please bear with me:

I believe your NSFetchRequest isn't populating your locations array with all annotations at once.
Try using a NSMutableArray. I've updated the code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Do your fetchRequest

//Then do the following, however I don't know exactly as what your `locations` are stored so you might need to change it a bit:
//I believe your annotations are kind of a Aerodromo class? So then:

for (Aerodromo *aerodromoAnn in fetchedObjects) {
    [tempLocations addObject:aerodromoAnn];
}
/
//Then update your original locations array:
locations = tempLocations.copy;

//update the main queue again
```

Sorry you'll have to check as I can't test it without the database

Comment: thanks, but the problem continues.... may be it is the queue declaration? I will post my new code

Comment: Updated my answer. Your new code isn't the problem now. Your problem isn't in the queue declaration but in the `regionWillChangeAnimated` and calling `[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];`

Comment: thanks for your help wkberg... I erased the regionWillChangeAnimated but the problem is still there.... I have spent a week trying to solve it, this is a real headache.... is there a way to do a loop with this and not show the map until all the annotations are ready?

Comment: Ah wait, since I was testing: could you move your `locations = foundObjects;` to the `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main() ^ {` part.

Comment: Thanks again, but the problem is still there... I post the last code with the changes that you suggested... the regionWillChangeAnimated is erased as well

Comment: Hmm I'm running out of possibility's... Edited my answer again.

Comment: Thanks wkberg.... I have tried with your solution, but I have not had good results.... as you say I think the problem is in NSFetchRequest....

Comment: I've updated the code for NSFetchRequest slightly, but that's all I can do for you with my knowledge at the moment.

Comment: it didn't work.... Thank you very much... I really appreciate your help... must be a problem in another part of code .... if I solve it, I tell you which was